# How to solve this unicode problem in reading text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I have a huge text file to process, and my code is the following:

```
freq_counter = collections.Counter()
    unigram_counter = collections.Counter()
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for i, batch in enumerate(read_batch(f, batch_size=1000)):
            logger.info("Batch {}".format(str(i)))
            frequency_with_batch(batch, freq_counter, unigram_counter, enable)
            if data_batch == i+1:
                break

def read_batch(file_handle, batch_size=1000):
    batch = []
    for line in file_handle:
        if not line:
            continue
        
        batch.append(line)
        if len(batch) == batch_size:
            yield batch
            batch.clear()
    if batch:
        yield batch
```

The encoding='utf8' has been working well until it processed the middle of the big text file. On a certain line, it reported the following error:

```
File "/data5/congmin/tool/utils/my_utils.py", line 484, in read_batch
    for line in file_handle:
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 6084-6085: invalid continuation byte
```

Does this mean some text are utf8 encoded and some are not utf8 in the same file?
I did some internet search and some suggested using encoding='latin-1' or encoding="ISO-8859-1". I generally have been using 'utf8' for reading and writing to file. For a big file like this, or a lot of text files, how should I use the encoding parameter if utf8 works most of the time?

EDIT:
I changed the encoding=utf8 to ISO-8859-1, the error message was gone. However, the characters output to text file are not readable as below:

```
ï¼  2225
ä¸  1412
    533
å   467
å¤  418
å   417
```

ADDITION:

I installed 'file' command on my ubuntu and found the file encoding:

```
file all.txt
 all.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

so it is actually utf-8 file. If it is utf8, why does it produce the error?

Comment: Files can be in encoded using different encoders. It is not normal to mix encodings in one file, but if the file was not actually encoded in UTF-8, it will fail on the first byte that violates the UTF-8 encoding rules. An encoder like Latin-1 will never fail, but if the file isn’t encoded in Latin-1 it will incorrectly decode to the wrong characters

Comment: @MarkTolonen What's the solution to this problem? For such huge file, this might happen often?

Comment: The solution is to use the correct encoding for the file. If you don’t know that, there are tools to guess but they don’t always guessed correctly

Comment: If the file is not utf-8, why has it processed the file correctly for a large portion of it? I suspect it may be due to some special characters to cause this. The whole file may be still utf8? What's the relationship between file's encoding versus character's encoding?

Comment: UTF8 follows specific encoding rules. The decoding of the file appears to work until it reads a byte in the sequence that violates the rules.

Comment: You should check carefully at the bytes you have errors (and maybe write it there). As other said, some file may have multiple encoding (this was frequent on old files). But it can just be an artefact of a program (or email client), which may split lines/characters in the middle of a sequence. A good way to debug: on `open` add `, error="backslashreplace")` and then look on text where you have the `\x..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your file is UTF-8 but has some illegal bytes in it. To suppress the exception and get a handle on what is wrong, open the file with `errors='backslashreplace'`. This will let you read te whole file and look at the troublesome bit.
From your earlier messages you already know the location of the first illegal byte.
It may be something as simple as a quotation from another document a
in a different encoding. (Should not happen, but does.)
Or it might be a corrupt file. (Ditto.)

Comment: 'backslashreplace' is a keyword used in Python?

Comment: No. Note that it is in quotes. The parameter `errors` to `open()` accepts several documented *string* values.